# node getting formed but cannot publish in pubsub xmpp

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, libstrophe

I am using libstrophe C library to Create xmpp clint.I am successfully able to create node(open node) and send request for subscription from other users,which get added.
Now when i try to publish,using the following stanza,

```
<iq type='set'
    from='hamlet@pratik.com/blogbot'
    to='pubsub.pratik.com'
    id='publish1'>
  <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
    <publish node='pratik'>
      <item id='123456'>
        <entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>
          <title>Soliloquy</title>
          <summary>
To be, or not to be
          </summary>
        </entry>
      </item>
    </publish>
  </pubsub>
```

I get,

```
<error code="501" type="cancel"><feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error>
```

Any suggestions?
am using ejabberd as server

Comment: please share your ejabberd module configuration part for pubsub

Comment: This is my ejabberd module configuration part,              {mod_pubsub,   [ % requires mod_caps  
                  {access_createnode, pubsub_createnode},  
                  {pep_sendlast_offline, false},  
                  {last_item_cache, false},  
                  %%{plugins, ["default", "pep"]}  
                  {plugins, ["flat", "hometree", "pep"]}  % pep requires mod_caps
                 ]},

Comment: i hope `access_createnode, pubsub_createnode` is not commented using `%` sign in your config file n more over have you set `{allow, all}` in that module configuration part |?

Comment: no its not commented.....can you share a stanza that does the function of publishing(other then in the spec)